# Extracting zip with password to another dir without foldername

Tags: python

I have this password protected zip folder:
folder_1\1.zip

When I extract this it gives me 
1\image.png

How can I extract this to another folder without its folder name? Just the contents of it: image.png

So far I have done all stackoverflows solutions and took me 11 hrs straight just to solve this.

```
import zipfile

zip = zipfile.ZipFile('C:\\Users\\Desktop\\folder_1\\1.zip', 'r')
zip.setpassword(b"virus")
zip.extractall('C:\\Users\\Desktop') <--target dir to extract all contents
zip.close()
```

**EDIT:**
This code worked for me: (Now I want many paths to be extracted at once, any ideas?

```
import os
import shutil
import zipfile

my_dir = r"C:\\Users\\Desktop"
my_zip = r"C:\\Users\\Desktop\\test\\folder_1\\1.zip"

with zipfile.ZipFile(my_zip) as zip_file:
    zip_file.setpassword(b"virus")
    for member in zip_file.namelist():
        filename = os.path.basename(member)
        # skip directories
        if not filename:
            continue

        # copy file (taken from zipfile's extract)
        source = zip_file.open(member)
        target = file(os.path.join(my_dir, filename), "wb")
        with source, target:
            shutil.copyfileobj(source, target)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `ZipFile.read()` method to read the specific file in the archive, open your target file for writing by joining the target directory with the base name of the source file, and then write what you read to it:

```
import zipfile
import os
zip = zipfile.ZipFile('C:\\Users\\Desktop\\folder_1\\1.zip', 'r')
zip.setpassword(b"virus")
for name in zip.namelist():
    if not name.endswith(('/', '\\')):
        with open(os.path.join('C:\\Users\\Desktop', os.path.basename(name)), 'wb') as f:
            f.write(zip.read(name))
zip.close()
```

And if you have several paths containing `1.zip` for extraction:

```
import zipfile
import os
for path in 'C:\\Users\\Desktop\\folder_1', 'C:\\Users\\Desktop\\folder_2', 'C:\\Users\\Desktop\\folder_3':
    zip = zipfile.ZipFile(os.path.join(path, '1.zip'), 'r')
    zip.setpassword(b"virus")
    for name in zip.namelist():
        if not name.endswith(('/', '\\')):
            with open(os.path.join('C:\\Users\\Desktop', os.path.basename(name)), 'wb') as f:
                f.write(zip.read(name))
    zip.close()
```

Comment: but how can I extract multiple paths to another folder

Comment: What do you mean by extracting multiple paths? What paths are you referring to?

Comment: like paths of other directories eg: C:\\Users\\Desktop\\folder_1, C:\\Users\\Desktop\\folder_2, C:\\Users\\Desktop\\folder_3

Comment: Do you mean to extract from multiple zip files, or do you mean to extract to multiple target directories?

Comment: You can simply iterate over the list of paths you have and join the path with the name of the zip file to open with `ZipFile`. I've updated my answer with an example.